# web2py: default controller line count?

Tags: python, linux, web2py

my web2py applications default controller, default.py is only 611 lines but its size on disk seems 24MByte, i check windows and linux systems, really 24 Mbyte seem, so web2py admin application is very slow

Comment: you could be more specific about what your question is about...

Comment: What happens if you copy the 611 lines to a new text file (using a text editor, not the admin app)?

Comment: yes, i try it with notepadd++ and 24 MB follow 240 KB but it must be max 40 KB, i think it is a bug, because i am copy block by block. for example, i copy 20 lines file size +50 KB :)

Comment: If you want a smaller default.py, you are allowed to have more than one controller. You can have as many controllers as you want. if you make a controller "extra.py" and it has a function "def newPage()", it's view will be "extra/newPage.html", not "default/newPage.html" as they have all been previously.